# No registra mis votos para la medalla Obligación Civil

Tags: soporte, medallas

Desde hace unas horas me dice que me faltan 3 votos para la medalla [Obligación Civil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) (300 votos).

He votado varias veces y no ha aumentado mi número de votos

Comment: Te refieres a la medalla [Obligación Civil](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty). Yo te diría que paciencia. Aunque tengas los requisitos de la medalla no siempre es inmediata su aparición. Espera un dia y si no aparece reportalo. Un saludo

Comment: A mi me ha pasado lo mismo. Las medallas, algunas no son inmediatas. Recuerda que los votos se pueden revertir hasta varios minutos después de votar, entonces los votos se deben bloquear para poder considerar la medalla.

Comment: @ArieCwHat no se si se esperará a bloquearse el voto, porque tras una edicion puedes cambiar votos sin importar cuando fueran.

Comment: No sean tan duros con una equivocacion, me calleron a palos con los negativos jejeje

Comment: @Mariano no entendi lo de los votos?

Comment: @VictorA. Cuando uno vota a un comentario, no cuenta para al medalla. Sólo cuentan los votos positivos o negativos a preguntas y respuestas

Comment: @Mariano, si si, eso lo entiendo, habia votado varias preguntas (entre ellas unas mias)

Comment: @Mariano Me explico mejor, con preguntas mias, me refiero a las respuestas que hicieron y fueron correctas en torno a mis preguntas formuladas jejeje

Comment: @Arie CwHat revertí tu cambio, pues la etiqueta [tag:medallas] ayuda a comprender la pregunta.

Comment: Lo siento @fedorqui, la etiqueta està en stack overflow español con preguntas asociadas, intentè eliminarla, pero no sucediò nada :( debe ser por que fuè migrada. Lueo olvide revertir el cambio.

Comment: @ArieCwHat supongo que [la pregunta original](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60687/medalla-de-votacion-no-registra-mis-votos?noredirect=1) se eliminará en una semana, tarda unos días en producirse automáticamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como puedes ver en esta imagen, ya se ha actualizado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paciencia la próxima vez. Aunque tengas los requisitos de la medalla no siempre es inmediata su aparición

Un saludo

Comment: jejeje sip, sera :) (y)